# Query timeout until reset SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Steps to reproduce (SQL Server 2008R2):

- We restore a .bak file
- We run the query (no other activity)
- It times out
- We restart sql server
- We run the query
- It runs really fast.

Reproduction rate 100%.

I've tried combinations of

```
  DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
  DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS 
  DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE 
  DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('ALL')
  DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (dbname)
  EXEC sp_updatestats  
  select * from master..sysprocesses where blocked <> 0
```

Nothing works, only restarting SQL Server.

I thought it would be just a bad plan, but expected `FREEPROCCACHE` to fix it, without restarting SQL Server. Is there some other cache I need to clear?

The query is not a transactional/blocking/locking style, mostly selects into and out of temporary tables it has created, and no other activities on the server.

I believe it must be a bad plan, but `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` didn't do the job.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: have you tried to stick `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on it?

Comment: The main problem is that this SQL is generated on the fly (adhoc), it's not a stored procedure. The user could change the query by ticking boxes in the UI. So we don't know when it should be recompiled or not. It maybe that we can detect the timeout and then force the recompilation (one time only). I will try and see if this has legs. Thanks. One thing I forgot to mention, the restart has to happen while the query is executing, or after it timed out, not before.

Comment: Does the query timesout everytime or only when selecting specific items on UI? you said that use can select what ever items they want so does it mean that it becomes only a problem when specific items are selected?

Comment: If you capture the SQL statement and run it within SQL management studio do you have the same problem ? You mentionned that there is no other activities, you mean, beside the UI used to generate de query or you checked the activity monitor and made sure nothing else was running ?

Comment: @SaUce Yes, we have our own 'query designer UI', it appears to only choose a bad plan when we generate SQL that uses a CTE to populate a temporary (#) table. If we change the designer so the query is slightly different or use a permanent workings table, the problem goes away. It also goes away if we reset the server (as mentioned).

Comment: @YanBrunet Activity Monitor - nothing else was running (except for usual reporting services statistics 'chatter'). If we use the SQL Profiler and copy the SQL sent to SQLServer by our app, paste into SQL management studio - the statement does not timeout! Which could indicate that it is a problem with the connection options? My current diagnosis is now being hampered, because when I restore the .bak file which previously failed - it won't fail any more.

Comment: If I can get it to fail consistently again, I will try and use WITH RECOMPILE, to see if can 'automatically recover', and interrogate the difference in connection options.

Comment: I was asking because we had similar issues where the problem was related to the number of thread used within SQL Server. But you would notice those threads within the Activity Monitor. You would also see your process go into waiting mode.

Although, the symptomes were pretty much the same and restarting the server was correcting this issues (since it killed other processes).

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have an open connection to the database, yould be that you are "standing on your own feet". when you restore a database you need exclusive access so drop who is in the database und rollback any transaction that's going on (you restore is going to whype any thing that was dony anyway). Then you can restore your database.

Now a restart of SQL server will close all active connections however there is an easier way ;-)

USE MASTER;
GO;

ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName]-->change this to your database name

SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

After that you can run your restore.

Have a nice day

Walter